# JWplayer. Change destination source with http request

Tags: actionscript-3, jwplayer

I'v got jwplayer source code from [github](https://github.com/jwplayer/jwplayer). I want to change some scripts and built the player. So, i need to change file source from javascript in flash. In javascript i'm setting some params "host" and "flv_id":

```
jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
    autostart: false,
    controlbar: "none",
    displayclick: "none",
    smoothing: true,
    stretching: "exactfit",
    icons: false,
    flashplayer: "/jwplayer.swf",
    file: "/videos/3aae1ef41d.flv",
    flv_id: "115554",
    host: "<?php echo $host; ?>",
    provider: "http",
    startparam: "start",
    height: 400,
    width: 650,
    events: {
        onComplete: function() {
        },
        onPause: function(event) {
        },
        onError: function() {
        }
    }
});
```

In flash i have some class, which can make post-request:

```
var post:Post = new Post("http://"+someparameters["host"]+"/video/flv");
post.variables.id = someparameters["flv_id"];
post.Send(Go);
```

Go - is success callback function that returns some flvlink.

```
Go(link:String):void { 
      //link - is source, that i need to play 
}
```

The player is playing the "/videos/3aae1ef41d.flv". But i want to play the source from Go(); I have class "Post", but i don't know the place to paste my code. Now, i haven't any changes in default source code. I don't know which file of player source code to edit. So, i need to know, how i can use my "Post" class to play video from Go function.

Comment: When you run the player right now with your changes, what happens? What are you ultimately trying to do?

Comment: The player is playing the "/videos/3aae1ef41d.flv". But i want to play the source from Go(); I have class "Post", but i don't know the place to paste my code. Now, i haven't any changes in default source code. I don't know which file of player source code to edit. So, i need to know, how i can use my "Post" class to play video from Go function

Comment: My Go() function is like 
function Go(link:String):void {
 //link - is source, that i need to play
}

Comment: I think i need to make some reconfig of source, but i'm affraid to brake the code.

Comment: What are you trying to reconfigure here? Can I see where you are running the modified player?

Comment: The problem is that i don't know the "here" place. I don't quite understand of "where running the player". I need to know, where I can get someparameters["host"] and someparameters["flv_id"] in action script. So, i'm trying to reconfigure the flv soursce in the player.

Comment: I mean a link. Why are you trying to do this in the source?

Comment: That's not very important. For example, I can not use the "file" property at all. My problem is to play video from my post result, not from javascript or embeded object. Why? This is the task before me. One of the reason - to ensure security. So, if you omit the reasons and just try to perform my task, can you help me?

Comment: Because we really don't provide such a use case or source code support for our player.

Comment: Well, we want to know why someone would want to change to source to simply load one file. If it is for security purposes, the browser will still report the file being played back, so doing so would ad minimal security.

Comment: Ok. If someone wants to parse my project for videos, he can see in html or javascript code the link of file. But in my decision, he can't get real link.
The essence of my idea is to use compiled swf object, which can make my operations. Any technology, such a php,html,javascript and etc. is accompanied by some "open source". It is always better to hide code without dirty.

Comment: If someone uses Firebug, Chrome Dev Tools, Charles, Fiddler, etc, any web proxy, they will be able to see the http requests and can rip out the files easily. Doing something like this, only adds minimal security.